# Is it possible to use GWT EntityProxy WITH RPC calls?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, requestfactory

I was reading about this **EntityProxy** feature in GWT 2.1+ and was wondering if you can use this proxy mechanism to avoid having to create DTOs and combine with regular RPC calls?

I have a command pattern which uses RPC mechanism, but as everybody knows, most of the time you have to round trip complex objects. But you usually end up coding a DTO which is usually a copy of your server side persistent object.

So can EntityProxy help you in this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EntityProxy is part of the [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) system and cannot be used with GWT-RPC.  The purpose of `EntityProxy` (and `ValueProxy`) is to avoid the need to code an entire DTO and all of the glue code that entails.  The `Request` objects used by RequestFactory roughly approximate a command pattern, since multiple `Request` objects can be queued within a single `RequestContext` and evaluated with a single round-trip to the server.

Comment: After a few hours of search I got to the same conclusion. Thank you.